# How to post just Array in retrofit Body for Android

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, retrofit2

In body I want to send just an ArrayList just as below

```
["item1","item2"]
```

And my API call is as below

```
@POST("{userId}/items")
fun postUpdateItems(
    @Path ("registrationId") registrationId: String,
    @Header(NetworkUtils.CONTENT_TYPE) contentType: String = NetworkUtils.CONTENT_TYPE_PARAMS,
    @Body body: List<String>
): Observable<Response<UpdateItemsResponse>>
```

But it does not work. I got the below error. I tried ArrayList Array None of them worked for me.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body.
```

Comment: what is your `NetworkUtils.CONTENT_TYPE_PARAMS`?

Comment: You are missing `userId` as parameter.

Comment: nope, iserId is not missing, I add the userId parameter when I call the method. 
I found the issue. On the handler I wrote get not host

Comment: I found the solution long ago but forget to add here. 

When I tried to add List<String> I got the error. 

Then I changed the the type to Set<String> (     mutableSetOf<String>().  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was not the `"userId"`. userId is a pathParam and should be added when we call the method. The issue was on the Handler. I was calling the wrong method.

I also have `getUpdatedItems` and on the handler I was calling it instead of `postUpdateItems` method.